# "'main': identifier not found" error in c++

Tags: c++

I keep getting this error and have no idea how to fix it because I don't see anything wrong with my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

#define GREEN "\033[32m"
#define RED   "\033[31m"
#define RESET "\033[0m"

void file_create(std::string name) {
    std::ifstream file(name);
    if (file.is_open()) {
    file.close();
    std::cout << "File already exists..." << std::endl;
    main();
    } 
    else {
    file.close(); std::ofstream newFile(name);
    if (newFile.is_open())
    std::cout << GREEN "New file successfully created..." << RESET << std::endl;
    else
    std::cout << RED "File could not be created" << RESET << std::endl;
    newFile.close();
    }
}

int main() {

}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but what exactly is your intent here?

Comment: In C++ it's not allowed to call the [`main`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function) function yourself. If you want a loop, use an actual loop in the `main` function instead.

Comment: im just messing around with file handling

Comment: With that said, the error is because in C++ you must *declare* all symbols before you try to use them. This should have been quite clear in any decent book, class or tutorial.

Comment: thank you ill make a loop in the main function

Answer (score 0):

The main function is not intended to be invoked from your code. It is also a nonsense since it is called automatically when program starts. But if you need some alternative main to be invoked upon some condition, you can call it inside your main function

```cpp
...
int alternative_main()
{
   place your program there
}
...
void file_create(std::string name) {
    ...
    if (file.is_open()) {
    ...
    alternative_main()
    } 
    else {
    ...
    }
}
```

Suppose your main looks like this

```cpp
int main() {
   file_create("myfile");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

#define GREEN "\033[32m"
#define RED   "\033[31m"
#define RESET "\033[0m"

int main(); // defined before file_create

void file_create(std::string name) {
    std::ifstream file(name);
    if (file.is_open()) {
    file.close();
    std::cout << "File already exists..." << std::endl;
    main();
    } 
    else {
    file.close(); std::ofstream newFile(name);
    if (newFile.is_open())
    std::cout << GREEN "New file successfully created..." << RESET << std::endl;
    else
    std::cout << RED "File could not be created" << RESET << std::endl;
    newFile.close();
    }
}

int main() {

}
```

Define int main() above file_create() so you can call it in file_create